# jQuery animate freezes unless I move my cursor in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

I am quite new to jQuery. I have an absolute positioned div that I want to move across the screen. This is the code that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cloud_white").animate({
    top: "100px",
    right: "-500px"
    },0).animate({
    marginRight: "2000px"
    },8000);
});
```

The div doesn't move unless I move my mouse cursor around in the browser. See here:
http://www.vardagbok.com/test.asp

Comment: I cannot find this code snippet in your page!

Comment: What are we looking for? All I see is two fields "Your Name" and "A day that is really special".

Comment: Sorry! Just updated my page~